# Unwanted Weird Autoexpansions

Tags: autocomplete, latex

A few months ago I started using VimTeX+Ultisnips to write TeX files like in [this](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) post. I originally copied the snippet from the author's [GitHub](https://github.com/gillescastel/latex-snippets/blob/master/tex.snippets) page but then made some changes on my own. However I've noticed that sometimes my Vim would trigger autoexpansions whereas the input does not define any snippet. For example, `((` triggers `\left( \right)<++>` (with the `<++>` at the end), `()` would trigger `()<++>`, `EVE` would trigger

```
\begin{verse}

\end{verse}<++>
```

and `EAR` would trigger

```
\left
\begin{array}{<+dimension+>}
        <+elements+>
\end{array}
\right<++>
```

I've checked my snippets file and I don't think any of the existing snippets would trigger these weird things above. Does anyone have once had a similar experience? Sorry I still know literally nothing about Vim besides using it for LaTeX, and I'm trying my best to describe the issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.